# How to understand how exception handling is working?

Tags: python, django, exception, google-api, google-bigquery

I have been fiddling around with raising exceptions for Google Big Query. I finally figured out how to make it work in the way it should work, but I don't really understand why it works. I am looking to gain a better understanding what is going on in my code. I have already scoured Stack Overflow and nothing seems to help.

***Here is my view:***

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def delete_table(request):  # Deletes table from Big Query
    project_id = request.POST.getlist('data[]')[0]
    dataset_id = request.POST.getlist('data[]')[1]
    table_id = request.POST.getlist('data[]')[2]

    bq = BigQuery(project_id)  # Instantiates BQ instance specific to project id
    try:
        bq.deleteTable(dataset_id, table_id)  # Calls deleteTable method from BQ instance

    except Exception, res:
        logger.debug(res)

    return Response('')
```

***Here is my delete method in my Big Query controller:***

```
    def deleteTable(self, datasetId, tableId):  

    try: 
        response, content = \
            self.http_auth.request("https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/%s/datasets/%s/tables/%s" % (self.PROJECT_ID, datasetId, tableId), "delete")

        content = json.loads(content)
        message = content['error']['message']
        raise Exception, message
    except:
        if response.status < 300:
            message = tableId + " Was Deleted."
            raise Exception, message
        else:
            raise Exception, message
```

I understand that the `view` is catching a raised error from the `bqcontroller`, I don't understand how the errors are being raised in the `bqcontroller`. Could someone please shed some light?

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception only to immediately catch it?

Comment: Your `try` block contains a `raise` statement, therefore it **always** raises an exception.  Surely you only want to raise an exception in the `except` block?  Also in the except block, since you're providing your own message, you are losing any specific message that may have been returned from the API call.

Comment: You seem to be using exceptions in place of a `return` statement. You are also catching *almost all exceptions*. Is there not a more specific exception (or set of exceptions) to catch here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code is, there is no real reason for the `try` because at the end of the `try` block you ***always*** raise an exception, so you always go to the `except` block.  So each time the code runs, it goes through the `try`, then hits the exception so goes to the `except` block where it raises an exception no matter which branch of the if/else statement you go to.

This code here does the same thing, it's just a little cleaner (less duplication) so you can see where the exceptions are being raised

```
def deleteTable(self, datasetId, tableId):
    GOOG_API_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/{}/datasets/{}/tables/{}'
    url = GOOG_API_ENDPOINT.format(self.PROJECT_ID, datasetId, tableId)

    response, json_content = self.http_auth.request(url, "delete")
    content = json.loads(json_content) # don't reassign same variable name

    if response.status < 300:
        message = tableId + " Was Deleted."
        raise Exception, message  # exception raised here or in else below
    else:
        message = content.get('error', {}).get('message')
        raise Exception, message
```

Although I wouldn't raise a generic `Exception`, I'd use one of the [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) or [define your own](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions)